# Can you send mystery skins to player on a different server?

Tags: league-of-legends

I want to send a mystery skin to my friend form EUNE server to EUW. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot send gifts across server. Your options to get a gift to your friend are very limited as the following restrictions are in place:

1. You must be level 15 to send a gift
2. The receiving player must be at least level 5
3. You must have been on each other's friend list for at least two weeks
4. The receiving player can not be banned or suspended (Leaverbuster, Tribunal, etc)

The options you have available to you are:

1. Pay for a server transfer to EUW
2. Send your CC information to your friend **<---- NOT RECOMMENDED**
3. Buy an RP card and send it to your friend *(unsure about EUNE to EUW compatibility)*

By no means should you **EVER** give your friend your password. The reason is not because your friend could steal your account or anything of that sort. You could potentially be banned for account sharing as they will notice the drastic difference in login location. The chance of this happening is slim, but it is a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to send gifts to other servers.

Without exchanging passwords or other private info, the only thing you could do is make a new account on EUW and level it up until you're able to gift.